# Date paginator throwing Uncaught type error on date click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Hi I am using  [Bootstrap Date Paginator](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator) to create pagination wizard. It is showing the UI but when I click on any date it is throwing errors

```
jquery-ui.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'empty' of undefined
at n._updateDatepicker (jquery-ui.min.js:10)
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:10)
at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.e.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui.min.js:10)
at DatePaginator._render (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:337)
at DatePaginator._init (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:126)
at new DatePaginator (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:31)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:426)
at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
```

and

```
jquery-ui.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui.min.js:10)
at Function.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
at m.fn.init.e.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui.min.js:10)
at DatePaginator._render (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:257)
at DatePaginator._select (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:208)
at DatePaginator._clickedHandler (bootstrap-datepaginator.js:182)
at HTMLDivElement.e (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4)
```

[image: Date Paginator UI]
My code is:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var currDate = new Date();
        var options = {
                      selectedDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                      selectedDate: moment(currDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),

                     };

         $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
       });

       CSS: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepaginator/1.1.0/bootstrap-datepaginator.css" />
       JS: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepaginator/1.1.0/bootstrap-datepaginator.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Does any one know why it throwing error ?

Is it may be bacuse of jquery-ui.min.js version.

Thank in advance

Comment: I removed the error by adding correct script tag as follows                         `code` <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>  `code`       but how can I get the selected date?

Comment: Can you update your question in regards for your fix issue on removing that specific error?

Comment: I updated the question, and I got the selected date by doing `code` var currDate = new Date();
 var options = {
      
      selectedDateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
   selectedDate: moment(currDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    onSelectedDateChanged: function (event, date) {

           var dateSelected = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
           
  };
 
 $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);   `code`

Comment: I implemented your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/Lzohjdkh/). I didn't encounter with your error.

Comment: I updated my code and it's working Ali, Thank You